# Sort List of objects by the number subtypes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a base class `vehicle` and have a list of different sub classes (`Car,Motorbike, Bicycle`). Now, I want to get the number of each subclass of the objects in the list, sorted in descending order.

```
Dim ListOfVehicle = New List(Of Vehicle)

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Car(50, "Rot", "Mercedes"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Car(70, "Grün", "Audi"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Car(20, "Violet", "Tesla"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Car(150, "Blau", "BMW"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Motorbike(70, "Grün", "Kawasaki"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Motorbike(120, "Rot", "Honda"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Motorbike(200, "Pink", "BMW"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Bicycle(20, "Blau", "Cube"))

ListOfVehicle.Add(New Bicycle(250, "Orange", "BMC"))
```

The output should look like this:
Car - 4
Motorbike - 3
Bicycle - 2

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you or teach you from scratch. If you want to do something, you need to learn how to do it and then do it. If what you do doesn't work, then is the time to post here, explaining your aim, you method and the incorrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.8) to count by the `GetType` key and sort in descending order. Then output by using the `Key` property and the `Count()` method:

```
Dim lookup = ListOfVehicle.ToLookup(Function(x) x.[GetType]()).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.Count())

For each vehicle in lookup
    Console.WriteLine(vehicle.Key.ToString() + " - " + vehicle.Count().ToString())
Next
```